# Installing tensorflow using bazel on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel, msys

I am trying to install tensorflow on windows 10 and I am following this link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

I have successfully installed bazel.  The problem is when I use this command

```
$ bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

to install tensorflow, msys shows the following error.

ERROR: C:/compiler/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:4855:1: no such target '@c                                                                                                                ython//:cython_binary': target 'cython_binary' not declared in package '' define                                                                                                               d by 
C:/tools/msys64/tmp/_bazel_myaccount/zgdsaeo4/external/cython/BUI                                                                                                                LD.bazel

and referenced by '//tensorflow/python:framework/fast_tensor_util.pyx_c                                                                                                                ython_translation'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' fai                                                                                                                led;

build aborted: Loading failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.472s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (132 packages loaded)

My guess is, it is looking for /cython folder in the wrong path. However, I have set the python path correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build TF on Windows using bazel. And had the same problem.
So as I needed only C++ library, I used the [following solution](https://joe-antognini.github.io/machine-learning/build-windows-tf) using CMake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried running ./configure as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4279#issuecomment-246003587). For windows you should [refer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11279)